# number of digits in the square root of a perfect square

Tags: arithmetic

number of digits in the square root of a perfect square with n digits is ceil(n/2).  We can get convinced of this result by following the division method.  My question is, is there analytical proof of this result?

Comment: $log \sqrt n=\frac {1}{2}log n $

Comment: simple and nice,  I missed it some how.  @N.S.JOHN.

Answer (score 3):

An $m$-digit integer is in the interval $[10^{m-1},10^m)$ and has a square in the interval  $[10^{2m-2},10^{2m})$ with $2m-1$ or $2m$ digits.

So to reverse, divide the number of digits in the square by two to give $\frac{2m-1}{2}= m-\frac12$ or $\frac{2m}{2}= m$ and round up to give the original integer $m$.

Answer (score 3):

**Claim:** For a positive integer $a$, suppose $a$ has $m$ digits and $a^2$ has $n$ digits. Then  $m = \left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil$.

**Proof:** We have
\begin{align*}
10^{m-1} \le a < 10^m \tag{1} \\
10^{n-1} \le a^2 < 10^n \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Squaring (1), we get
$$
10^{2m-2} \le a^2 < 10^{2m}
$$
Combining with (2), it follows that
$$
10^{n-1} < 10^{2m} \implies m > \frac{n-1}{2} \implies m \ge \frac{n}{2}
$$
and
$$
10^{2m-2} < 10^n \implies m < \frac{n+2}{2} \implies m < \frac{n}{2} + 1.
$$
Therefore $m$ is an integer greater than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$ and less than $\frac{n}{2} + 1$. Thus by definition of the ceiling function, we must have
$$
m = \left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil.
$$

Comment: @igael thanks, i fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The number of digits of a number $n$ in base $b$ is given by

$$\lfloor\log_b (n)\rfloor + 1$$

Now we have

\begin{align*}
\lfloor \log_b(\sqrt{n}) \rfloor + 1 &= \left\lfloor\frac{1}{2} \log_b(n) \right\rfloor + 1 \\
&= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}\lfloor\log_b(n)\rfloor +1 & \text{if } \lfloor\log_b(n)\rfloor \text{ is even} \\ \frac{1}{2}\lfloor\log_b(n)\rfloor + \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } \lfloor\log_b(n)\rfloor \text{ is odd} \end{cases} \\
&= \left\lceil \frac{1}{2} \left(\lfloor \log_b(n) \rfloor + 1 \right)\right\rceil.
\end{align*}